# After import FormsModule, NgModel still doesn't work

Tags: angular

I got this error.
**Can't bind to 'NgModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.**
    I already import FormsModule in app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmployeeComponent} from './employee/employee.component'

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, EmployeeComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is code app.component.ts code:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
            <div>
            Name : <input [(NgModel)]='name'/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            You entered : {{name}}
            </div>
`,
})
export class AppComponent {
    name: string = "John";
}
```

Did anyone knows where is the problem?

Comment: Be more attentive since you write case-sensitive code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

**From**

```
  Name : <input [(NgModel)]='name'/>
```

**To**

```
  Name : <input [(ngModel)]='name'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is `[(ngModel)]` not `[(NgModel)]`